# How to copy filtered item from an arry as well as a single element

Tags: javascript

I have two array.

```
const attributes = [
  { label: 'Reference', value: 1 },
  { label: 'Composition', value: 2 },
  { label: 'Construction', value: 3 },
  { label: 'P', value: 4 },
  { label: 'Q', value: 5 },
  { label: 'R', value: 6 }
];

const initialData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    fieldId: uuidv4(),
    attributeId: 1,
    isColorSense: true,
    isSizeSense: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    fieldId: uuidv4(),
    attributeId: 2,
    isColorSense: true,
    isSizeSense: true
  }
];
```

I need an array which contains any single item from `attributes` (based on my condition)
and filer those item which are not in `initialData`.
Suppose, if I call like this `getFilteredAttributes(1)`, I want to get this array

```
[
  { label: 'Reference', value: 1 },
  { label: 'Construction', value: 3 },
  { label: 'P', value: 4 },
  { label: 'Q', value: 5 },
  { label: 'R', value: 6 }
]
```

I tried like this. Here `preSelectedAttribute` pushed into `filteredAttribute` lastly.

```
  const getFilteredAttributes = prevAttribute => {
    let filteredAttribute = [];
    const usedAttributeIds = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.attributeId))];

    const remainingAttributes = attributes.filter(item => !usedAttributeIds.includes(item.value));
    filteredAttribute = [...remainingAttributes];

    if (prevAttribute !== '') {
      const preSelectedAttribute = attributes.find(item => item.value === prevAttribute);
      filteredAttribute.push(preSelectedAttribute);
    }

    return filteredAttribute;
  };
```

how do i push `preSelectedAttribute` first into `filteredAttribute` with optimized code?

Comment: its an Id which is used to filter item from `attributes`

Comment: So, `prevAttribute` object needs to be at the beginning of the output array and remaining filtered objects needs to come after that?

Comment: Yes. You got me.

Comment: is `prevAttribute` optional? Is `value` property unique for each object?

Comment: `prevAttribute` is not optional. Its mandatory  and  `value` property is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to use `unshift` instead of `push` for `preSelectedAttribute`
- A `Set` is created in your code because [`Set.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) lookups are much faster than `Array.includes`. So, don't convert the Set to an array.
- `filter` returns a new array. There is no need to use [...remainingAttributes]

---

Some alternatives:

- Get the `prevAttribute` object first
- Add `prevAttribute` to the `Set` because that also needs to be removed from `filter`
- return an array of filtered objects with `prevAttribute` object at the beginning

```js
function getFilteredAttributes(prevAttribute) {
  const prev = attributes.find(o => o.value === prevAttribute),
        set = new Set(initialData.map(i => i.attributeId)).add(prevAttribute)
  
  return [prev, ...attributes.filter(a => !set.has(a.value))]
}
```

```js
const attributes = [{label:"Reference",value:1},{label:"Composition",value:2},{label:"Construction",value:3},{label:"P",value:4},{label:"Q",value:5},{label:"R",value:6}],
      initialData=[{id:1,attributeId:1,isColorSense:true,isSizeSense:true},{id:2,attributeId:2,isColorSense:true,isSizeSense:true}];

function getFilteredAttributes(prevAttribute) {
  const prev = attributes.find(o => o.value === prevAttribute),
        set = new Set(initialData.map(i => i.attributeId)).add(prevAttribute)
  
  return [prev, ...attributes.filter(a => !set.has(a.value))]
}

console.log(getFilteredAttributes(4))
```

---

You could also use a simple loop and add objects to the end or beginning of the array based on conditions

```js
function getFilteredAttributes(prevAttribute) {
  const output = [],
        set = new Set(initialData.map(i => i.attributeId))

  for (const o of attributes) {
    if (o.value === prevAttribute)
      output.unshift(o)
    else if (!set.has(o.value))
      output.push(o)
  }

  return output
}
```

```js
const attributes = [{label:"Reference",value:1},{label:"Composition",value:2},{label:"Construction",value:3},{label:"P",value:4},{label:"Q",value:5},{label:"R",value:6}],
      initialData=[{id:1,attributeId:1,isColorSense:true,isSizeSense:true},{id:2,attributeId:2,isColorSense:true,isSizeSense:true}];

function getFilteredAttributes(prevAttribute) {
  const output = [],
        set = new Set(initialData.map(i => i.attributeId))

  for (const o of attributes) {
    if (o.value === prevAttribute)
      output.unshift(o)
    else if (!set.has(o.value))
      output.push(o)
  }

  return output
}

console.log(getFilteredAttributes(4))
```

Comment: @Nasir I updated answer on how to make it work with your existing code

Comment: Thanks. But there is an issue which I not explained but added to my code block. The issue is, if i pass `''` with `prevAttribute` it needs to be return only filteredArray. not inclued `prevAttribute` object. 
doesn't matter, i can now modify it. Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code.

```
const getFilteredAttributes = prevAttribute => {
    let filteredAttribute = [];
    let preSelectedAttribute;
    const usedAttributeIds = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.attributeId))];

    if (prevAttribute !== '')
      preSelectedAttribute = attributes.find(item => item.value === prevAttribute);
    
    filteredAttribute = attributes.filter(item => !usedAttributeIds.includes(item.value));
    if(preSelectedAttribute)
      return [preSelectedAttribute, ...filteredAttribute];
    return filteredAttribute;
  };
```